# What is difference between strong and copy?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between strong vs copy in objective-c? Which one should i be using?

I know copy prevents the value of the instance variable from changing if set with a mutable string that is later changed itself. Anything else?

Comment: "Which one should I be using?" It depends upon your needs. Sometimes you need to make sure that your class has its own copy or that it cannot be mutated, in which `copy` is correct. Sometimes you don't care and really want a `strong` reference to some other object. Both `strong` and `copy` (as well as `weak`) have situations where they are, respectively, appropriate. Ask a question about a particular scenario, and we can help you (if it's not already obvious after reading the post to which Josh referred you).

Answer (score 1):

`strong` increases retain counter of an object by 1.

`copy` creates an object's copy with retain counter 1.

If you use ARC you can't access to retain counter, but the approach is the same as for MRC.

Comment: This is incorrect for copy.

Comment: `copy` of an immutable object such as NSString just increases the retain count. `copy` of a mutable object makes an immutable copy with a retain count of 1. This is for properties of immutable objects.

Comment: That is why `copy` is recommended for `NSString`, `NSNumber`, it only makes a copy of mutable to immutable.